# AppEngine Task Queue Namespaces and Quota

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

When using namespaces with Task Queues is the quota applicable across all namespaces or do namespaced queues actually work as separate queues?
Example: the 500 task invocations per second per queue are a limit for all namespaces on the same queue or per namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quota is applicable for all namespaces

> Task names are shared across all namespaces. You cannot create two tasks of the same name, even if they use different namespaces. If you wish to use the same task name for many namespaces, you can simply append each namespace to the task name.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Using_namespaces_with_the_Task_Queue)